# Image is not loading in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on ionic 3. I updated ionic-cli, nodejs and cordova versions in the project. After updating the version, the images are not loading in android. But It's working fine in the browser. I applied all the suggestions but it's not fixed yet.

**The error which I am getting.**

```
Appi_demo_a.png:1 GET http://localhost/assets/icon/Appi_demo_a.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am doing to fix it.

**add this in confix.xml**

```
 <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">spiapi.demo.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**version details**

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI          : 6.12.1 
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:   
Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : 5.0.4, android 9.0.0, browser
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.7, (and 17 other plugins) 
NodeJS            : v14.15.0 
npm               : 6.14.8
```